# Terminal Restart Updates Rails and Ruby Versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601098/1626767) fixed my previous problems/errors, but when I restart my terminal and start a new session the versions of Rails updates from 2.0.2 to 4.0.0 and Ruby updates from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3p448, which then causes my previous errors to appear.

How can I permanently keep the settings from [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601098/1626767) so that I don't have to re-enter those 7 commands again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set a default as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282326/how-to-make-a-gemset-in-rvm-the-default). So it might be something like `rvm use 1.8.7@your_gemset_name --default`. That will set the ruby and gemset to what you need.

Comment: Thanks Scott for being so nice and helping me out! There's so many mean people on here to new users like me, but helpful and nice people give me hope :)

Comment: Yeah they kind of need two Stackoverflows, one for beginners where responders should be nice and another for hard core types where they can rip on each other. Sometimes I have gone to Reddit with more basic questions. The answers can be less helpful but the people better with newcomers