# Upgrading to latest version of Ruby

Tags: ruby

I understand that rvm allows us to run multiple versions of ruby. Are ruby gems installed to a specific version of ruby? Say I upgraded to the latest version of ruby 2.1.1 and want to use that as my default, do I have to reinstall the ruby gems from the earlier version of ruby to this version?

Comment: https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `rvm install`, you will have to install your gems anew. If you use `rvm upgrade`, the gems will be migrated if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [RVM documentation](http://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems):

RVM creates a new completely separate gem directory for each version of ruby. In addition you can separate this further and have a set of gems per project/application/gerbil color... see the gemsets for more details on using sets of gems. [...]

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm --default use <RUBYVERSION>
```

For example,

```
rvm --default use 2.1.1
```

[You can check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282326/how-to-make-a-gemset-in-rvm-the-default/22342480#22342480). And check out [RVM Documentation](http://rvm.io/) too.